# Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process. current row version identifier

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

```
select 
"ARTRNORD_D_PK",
"ARTRNORD_PK",
"Qty1",
"RATE",
"DISCPER",
"STX1PER",
"ORDLINEDSC",
rate*qty1 as gross_amt,
apex_item.text (30,
NULL,
80,
100,
'style="width:190px" ',
'f08_' || '#ROWNUM#'
)  as "T1"
from "#OWNER#"."ARTRNORD_D"
where "ARTRNORD_PK" = :P99_ARTRNORD_PK
```

I want to create a dummy text field column in tabular form but I am getting error

Comment: And what *is* the error?  BTW, do you really have mixed-case column names in an Oracle database?  That's a sure way to make life difficult.

Comment: i need one dummy column to calculate two column in text field in tabular form.

Comment: So I ask a second time ... what is the error?  All you've done is show a query against YOUR tables and stated that you have an error, but you didn't say what the error is.  Some oracle error code? The query runs but gives the wrong result?